# How to optimize the query, adding rowNumber in where clause

Tags: sql-server

In a table I have more than 700,000 records. When I run this query it takes more than 3 minutes to fetch the rows, and returns 390 records based on rowNum. Is there way to optimize this query?

```
SELECT  ID, Lat, Long,  SDateTime,
row_number() OVER (partition BY [ID] ORDER BY [SDateTime] DESC) AS rowNum
into #temp
FROM    
dbo.myTable WITH (NOLOCK)

select * from #temp where rowNum = 1    -- returns 390 records
drop table #temp
```

Can I select data in one query without putting it in temp table? like this:

```
SELECT  ID, Lat, Long,  SDateTime,
row_number() OVER (partition BY [ID] ORDER BY [SDateTime] DESC) AS rowNum

FROM    
dbo.myTable WITH (NOLOCK)
where (row_number() OVER (partition BY [ID] ORDER BY [SDateTime] DESC)) = 1
```

Comment: can you add index on [ID] and [SDateTime] column

Comment: index is already added, but still take time.

Answer (score 0):

try doing this !

```
select * from 
(
SELECT  ID, Lat, Long,  SDateTime,
row_number() OVER (partition BY [ID] ORDER BY [SDateTime] DESC) AS rowNum
FROM    
dbo.myTable WITH (NOLOCK)
)x
where x.rowNum=1
```

Comment: Can you please explain your answer in brief?

Answer (score 0):

This should do the job, but it will work very well with an index on (id,SDateTime)

```
;with d as (
  select distinct id
  from myTable
)
select 
  mt.*
from d
cross apply (
  select top 1 *
  from myTable m
    on m.id = d.id
  order by [SDateTime] DESC
) mt
```